# reactjs add new row to material-table editable

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, material-table

I want to add a new row with editable-table. I need buttons like Save and Cancel when adding a new line. I want to add a new line with the + button on the Toolbar.

that is, when the add button is pressed. new row will be added on the table. I want the Save and Cancel buttons for the new line.

[image]

I want to add and save a new record with the + button on the top right. how can I do that ?

https://codesandbox.io/s/gifted-nash-2s5ff

`

```
 <MaterialTable
  actions={[
    rowData => ({
      icon: Edit,
      tooltip: "Edit",
      onClick: (event, rowData) => {
        isRowUpdating(rowData, true);
      }
    }),
    rowData => ({
      icon: DeleteOutline,
      tooltip: "Delete",
      onClick: (event, row) => {
        this.bountyModalDeleteForm();
      }
    }),


    {
      icon: Add,
      onClick: (event, rowData) => {
        console.log('New record !');
      },
      isFreeAction: true,
      tooltip: 'New record',
    }
  ]}

  components={{
    EditRow: props => {
      const newRowData = {
        ...props.data,
        id:  props.data.id,
        user: props.data.user,
      };

      return (
        <MTableEditRow
          {...props}
          data={newRowData}
          onEditingCanceled={(mode, rowData) => {
            isRowUpdating(rowData, false);
          }}
          onEditingApproved={(mode, newData, oldRowData) => {
            isRowUpdating(props.data, false);
            this.handleSubmitUpdate(newData);
          }}
        />
      );
    },

    Toolbar: props => (
      <div style={{background: "blue"}}>
        <StyledMTableToolbar {...props} />
      </div>
    ),
```

`

Comment: Instead of adding the actions yourself, just use the editable out of the box: https://material-table.com/#/docs/features/editable

Comment: I don't want a standard,
I want to use a customizable table.  so I just want to use the codes on the codesandbox

Comment: I want to add a new row on the table.

Comment: It is not clear what you ask for. Pressing + button doesn't add a new row?

Comment: No because its his own action, not the edit action provided by the table, you needs to hack into the data manager via ref I guess. But I do not know why he wants to customize it like that.

Comment: When I press the + button, I need to add a new line to the table. @Domino987 how can I do that